# Netbeans CRUD web application combobox state not saved

Tags: crud

```
phonerecord table
-----------------
phonecallID
...
[whocompany] -> clients.clientID
[staffanswered]  -> staff.staffID

clients table
-------------
clientID
clientname

staff table
-----------
staffID
staffname
```

[create new record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEMpm.png)

[list new record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4i8hC.png)

As you can see in the images after adding a new record then go to View page, two combo boxes are not selected. Their state after saving the new record is not carried over to View page.

```
<h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListPhonerecordTitle_whocompany}"/>
                            </f:facet>                            
                            <h:selectOneMenu id="whocompany" value="#{phonerecordController.selected.whocompany}" title="#{bundle.EditPhonerecordTitle_whocompany}" >
                                <f:selectItems value="#{clientsController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"/>
                            </h:selectOneMenu>
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListPhonerecordTitle_staffanswered}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:selectOneMenu id="staffanswered" value="#{phonerecordController.selected.staffanswered}" title="#{bundle.EditPhonerecordTitle_staffanswered}" >
                                <f:selectItems value="#{staffController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"/>
                            </h:selectOneMenu>                     
                        </h:column>
```

I think i need to modify controller class(s).

Answer (score 0):

fixed it

```
<f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListPhonerecordTitle_whocompany}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.whocompany.clientname}"/>
```